# C++ WinRT - Any way to speed up DispatchTimer ( like in microseconds )?

Tags: performance, timer, windows-runtime

It is possible to speed up the DispatchTimer ?

The default timer routine is tested at maximum 30fps, average with XAML UI like TextBlock transforming its location.

Below I purposely set interval to 0 milliseconds, the timer routine speeded up to almost 60fps but display resulted in animation in sync or regulated properly.

```
int MainPage::OnInit()
{
...
    m_tm.Tick({ this, &MainPage::OnTimer });
    std::chrono::milliseconds ms( 0 );
    m_tm.Interval( ms );
    m_tm.Start();
...
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? All sorts of code will run on the dispatcher thread, so even if you make it tick every 1 microsecond, you can't control how long each tick will execute for.

Comment: I try to speed up the timer routine so the bitmap drawing process can accomplish 60fps.

Comment: XAML is probably not the best technology if you need 60fps bitmap animation. Have you looked at Win2D?

Comment: Yes, I did, is just that Win2D is not encouraging single pixel drawing but might be useful on other areas. However, I am ok with current 30fps under DispatchTimer :o)